# How to set default web cam

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, webcam

I have installed CamTwist on my MacBook (mid-2015 - Retina display).

Now every app uses that by default.

I want the default webcam to be the FaceTime HD camera installed in my MacBook.

How do I make every app use that webcam by default?

Comment: What have you already tried to solve the problem? Things like preferences of CamTwist, preferences of the applications, System Preferences, CamTwist FAQ/Support site etc?

Comment: @nohillside I couldn't find an option in System Preferences, there's nothing in CamTwist either. I was expecting to find it in System Preferences, like setting the default audio devices.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://camtwiststudio.com/support/faq/ the following seems to apply to your situation.

[image]

PS: Development for the application may have stopped, the web site looks rather outdated.

Comment: My preferences look completely different... I have 2016 version of CamTwist 3.2. Looks like I'm out of date though, they have 3.4.2 now. Not sure where the 2013 number comes from? It only runs on macOS 10.10+  which came out in 2014

Comment: @theonlygusti I only noticed that the latest blog entry is from 2013.

Comment: This is a great find. I was going to say unplug the camera when you don’t want it default. I can’t think why you would have it connected and not want it to run, but perhaps there’s a reason I didn’t consider.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this (so far) by quitting Camtwist and then restarting the computer.  That deactivates the Camtwist driver.  My Camtwist (latest version) is missing any preference option to deactivate the driver etc.  I made sure it wasn't in my login items or anywhere else that might launch at startup!